# How to add "NeverPublish" field to lucene index on Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-lucene

I am working on a small back-end application on Sitecore 8. As a feature, the application has to quickly search through thousands of items and find which one is not publishable. As far as I know I need to add relevant field to the lucene index. I did a research on google and found people can access to this property through `__Never publish` field. For example they use it on sitecore powershell to switch this boolean property ( I tried it and it works).

However I am struggling to make this working in Lucene index. I added something like this to my index definition on master database:

```
<configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration">
          <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="title" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              ... 
<field fieldName="__Never publish" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
</fieldNames>
</fieldMap>
</configuration>
```

Any field I add to index (even some built-in fields) can get indexed and the content can get stored as well. (like the "title" in the above example) but I don't understand why the neverpublish field doesn't.

I looked into other configuration files and found it is excluded from being indexed inside `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` and the definition is like this:

`<exclude hint="list:ExcludeField">
....
<NeverPublish>{9135200A-5626-4DD8-AB9D-D665B8C11748}</NeverPublish>
....
<exclude>`

Then I commented the it out but still no luck. I wonder if I am referencing the field name correctly or there is anything else I should no. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

This configuration works fine for me:

*<field fieldName="__never publish"               storageType="YES"  indexType="TOKENIZED"   vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.Boolean"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />*

It differs from yours with type: type="System.Boolean"

p.s.: And of course excluding from search should be commented as you mentioned above

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. let me try again. Thanks for hint